# Unexpected results with excercise in java

Tags: java

I have an exercise about raising certain numbers to a given power.
The exact one I have problems with:
We use the integers a, b, and n to create the following series:

```
 (a + 2^0 * b), (a + 2^0 * b + 2^1 * b), ... ,(a + 2^0 * b + 2^1 * b + ... + 2^n-1 * b)
```

You are given q queries in the form of a, b, and n. For each query, print the series corresponding to the given a, b, and n values as a single line of n space-separated integers.

Input Format 
The first line contains an integer, q, denoting the number of queries. Each line i of the q subsequent lines contains three space-separated integers describing the respective ai, bi, and ni values for that query.

Output Format
For each query, print the corresponding series on a new line. Each series must be printed in order as a single line of n space-separated integers.

I tried this code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math.*;

class Playground {
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        int q = in.nextInt();

        for(int i = 0; i < q; i++) {
            int a = in.nextInt();
            int b = in.nextInt();
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int num = a;
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                num += (((int) Math.pow(2, j)) * b);
                System.out.print(num + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }


    }
}
```

But it failed the test, even though the "Expected output" and the actual output looked the same. I tried searching for other solutions, but the ones I found were not that different from my own.

Input

```
2
0 2 10
5 3 5
```

Expected Output

```
2 6 14 30 62 126 254 510 1022 2046
8 14 26 50 98
```

Output

```
2 6 14 30 62 126 254 510 1022 2046
8 14 26 50 98
```

Comment: If the expected and actual output are identical you should probably contact whoever is in charge of the "solution checker". I'm not sure what answer you expect here

Comment: I expected the answer I did get below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly related to the trailing space in your output:

```
2 6 14 30 62 126 254 510 1022 2046 | <<= Trailing space
8 14 26 50 98 | <<= Trailing space
```

Fix your output as follows:

```
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    if (j != 0) {
        System.out.print" ");
    }
    num += (((int) Math.pow(2, j)) * b);
    System.out.print(num);
}
```

Note that you can avoid calling `Math.pow` at all, because powers of 2 can be computed using bit shift expression `1 << j`; multiplication of `b` by `1 << j` is equivalent to shifting `b` left by `j`:

```
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    if (j != 0) {
        System.out.print" ");
    }
    num += (b << j);
    System.out.print(num);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, I really did not think the following space could cause the problem, but this way it was accepted.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int TestCase = sc.nextInt();

        while (TestCase-- > 0) {
            int a = 0, b = 0, n = 0;
            a = sc.nextInt();
            b = sc.nextInt();
            n = sc.nextInt();

            int sum = a + b;

            for (int i = 1; i < n;) {
                System.out.print(sum + " ");
                sum += ((int) Math.pow(2, i) * b);
                i++;
                if (i == n) {
                    System.out.print(sum);
                }

            }

            System.out.println();

        }
        sc.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String []argh){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=in.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
            int a = in.nextInt();
            int b = in.nextInt();
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int power = 1,sum=0;
            for(int j=0;j < n;j++)
            {
                sum=a+(power*b);
                System.out.print(sum+" ");
                power = power * 2;
                power++;  
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        in.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//where 2^0*b, 2^0*b + 2^1*b, 2^0*b + 2^1*b + 2^2*b .....,2^(k+1) - 1


import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;

class Solution{
    public static void main(String []argh){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=in.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){

            int a = in.nextInt();
            int b = in.nextInt();
            int n = in.nextInt();
            int count = 0;
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++) {

                    System.out.print((int)(a+b*(Math.pow(2,j + 1)-1))+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
            if(j==0){
                output = output + (a + (int)Math.pow(2,j) * b);
            }
            else{
                output = output + ((int)Math.pow(2,j) * b);
            }
            System.out.print(output+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
```

Comment: (a + 2^0 * b), (a + 2^0 * b + 2^1 * b), ... ,(a + 2^0 * b + 2^1 * b + ... + 2^n-1 * b)

Comment: (a + 2^0 * b), (a + 2^0 * b + 2^1 * b), ... ,(a + 2^0 * b + 2^1 * b + ... + 2^n-1 * b)
when j=0 then a=a
                  +2^0*b= + Math.pow(2,j)*b
when j increments it adds the previous result to the output
 (a + 2^0 * b + 2^1 * b)  can be break down into a+2^0*b is stored in output and 2^1*b= Math.pow(2,j)*b

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following simple method to solve this problem but mind it, you can decrease time complexity using recursion, here I am going without recursion:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.Math;
class Solution{
    public static void main(String []argh){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=in.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
            int a = in.nextInt();
            int b = in.nextInt();
            int n = in.nextInt();
            double sum=0;
            for(int j=1;j<=n;j++)
            {
                sum=a;
                for(int k=0;k<j;k++)
                {
                    sum=sum+(b*Math.pow(2, k));
                }
                System.out.print((int)sum+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class Solution{
    public static void main(String []argh){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=in.nextInt();
        int a =0,b=0,n=0;
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
             a = in.nextInt();
             b = in.nextInt();
             n = in.nextInt();
             arrange(a,b,n);
        }
        in.close();
    }

        public static void arrange(int a,int b,int n){
        int sum = a+b;
        for(int j=1; j<=n; j++){
            System.out.print(sum+" ");
            sum+=((Math.pow(2,j))*b);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding comments will make this answer more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the full code with more optimized and cleaned - It will run all your test cases

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Solution
{
  public static void main(String []argh)
  {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int t=in.nextInt();
    
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++)
    {
        int a = in.nextInt();
        int b = in.nextInt();
        int n = in.nextInt();
    
        int s=0;
        s=s+a;

        for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
          s+=(Math.pow(2,j))*b;
          System.out.print(s+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    in.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Solution{
    public static void main(String []argh){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=in.nextInt();
            for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
                int result = 0;
                int a = in.nextInt();
                int b = in.nextInt();
                int n = in.nextInt();

            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++ ){
                if(j==0){
                    result = result + (a + (int)Math.pow(2,j) * b);// for (a + 2^0 * b)
                }
                else{
                    result = result + ((int)Math.pow(2,j) * b);  //  for (a + 2^0 * b + 2^1 * b)
                }
                System.out.print(result+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    in.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Comment: (a + 2^0 * b)is same as   result = result + (a + (int)Math.pow(2,j) * b);

Answer (score 0):

Try this completed code...

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Solution{
    public static void main(String []argh){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=in.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
            int a = in.nextInt();
            int b = in.nextInt();
            int n = in.nextInt();
            
            for(int x=0; x<n; x++){
                a+=(Math.pow(2,x)*b);
                System.out.print(a+" ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        in.close();
    }
}
```